# Android - AlarmManager set random delays between alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to run a code every x hours but I also want to keep some randomness between the times the code gets triggered.

I was trying with AlarmManager by setting and canceling with some random delay but I didn't manage to make it work.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverAux" />
```

According to developer.android

```
   Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. 
There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). 
Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.
```

from  [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://here)

Comment: I edited the question to show my receiver as well. Thanks

Comment: add "." before android name. That might be the problem. Btw What are trying to do with intent?

Comment: the "." I think it doesn't make any difference. The intent is the description of the operation to be performed

Comment: I have never used explicit Actions to call brodcast reciever. Intent alarmclass = new Intent(context, BroadcastReceiverAux.class); Try setting intent in this way.

Comment: Btw you do know that "set" method is actually setting inexact alarms right? You set 3 seconds later but it might call minutes later in order to save battery. Try setting "setexact" to check if everything else is correct in your app.

Comment: really? So if I just use setRepeating it will automatically add this random delays that I want, to save battery? That would be awesome to me

Comment: I managed to find a way of forcing the delay time. I shared the code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way of doing this. I'm sharing the code in case you also need it.

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tribta.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="test"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Alarm"></receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":my_service" >
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.tribta.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        this.startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**:

```
package com.tribta.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        alarm.setAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.setAlarm(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Alarm.java**, where you can put YOUR code:

```
package com.tribta.test;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        // Put here YOUR code.
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(300); // Vibrate for 300 milliseconds

        cancelAlarm(context);
        setAlarm(context);

        wl.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

        Random r = new Random();
        int ri = r.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1; // random integer between 7 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive),
        int delay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * ri; // Millisec * Second * Minute * hours

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + delay, pi);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```